# Can anyone explain why an element's content still showing after removing

Tags: jquery

I might sound novice but quite surprising to me and i need to know what is really happening.

I did this:

```
var elem=$('#div');
 elem.remove();
alert(elem.text());
```

Surprisingly i still get alert with the element content.

Where as, if i do this

```
var elem=$('#div');
 elem.remove();
alert( $('#div').text()); //undifined
```

Comment: You could still re-add the element elsewhere into the DOM; it's not gone forever from existence once you `.remove()` it.

Comment: @AKX.. Quite interesting to know that...If i know right, it means mere having or declaring a variable elem=$('#div'); already holds or save the contents, and datas of the element even before using elem.text()?

Comment: Yes, `$()` will select the elements from the DOM and you'll have references to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you remove the element from the DOM, but still have the reference to it in your variable, which you then alert it's text.

In the second example, you again remove the element from the DOM, and then search the DOM again for an element with id div, which is not found, thus returning undefined when it's text is alerted.

Comment: Quite interesting to know that...If i know right, it means mere having or declaring a variable elem=$('#div'); already holds or save the contents, and datas of the element even before using elem.text()?

Comment: Also, will it be be necessary to do elem=null; to clear it from memory?

Comment: Yes, when you assign the jQuery object of a DOM element (or also the native object of a DOM element), you'll have access to all of it's **current** properties. And, if you want to help garbage collection you can set it to null if no longer used ;)